# automatic allocation in c

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

```
1  #define SOME_OPERATION(a,b) a+b
2
3  typedef struct {
4   char* name;
5   int nameLen;
6   int val;
7  } SomeType;
8
9  SomeType* f(int x, int y, int z, char* name)
10 {
11  SomeType a;
12
13  assert(name != NULL);
14  a.name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
15  strcpy(a.name, name);
16  assert( (a.nameLen = strlen(name)) > 0 );
17
18  a.val = SOME_OPERATION(x,y) * z;
19  if (a.val < 0) {
20  return NULL;
21 }
22
23 return &a;
24 }
```

This code compiles successfully, but contains a number of significant errors.
For example in line 14, there it doesn't check if malloc returns NULL.
My question is, if this fixed code works for this specific issue:

```
if(!a.name)
{
  //or should be in addition free(a)
  return NULL;
}
```

When I write `SomeType a`, Does it mean that a new pointer to SomeType was allocated?

Comment: You don't need to `free()` a null pointer (*it does nothing if you do*). `if (!ptr)` is the same as `if (ptr == NULL)`.

Comment: I don't understand the question? You say the code has some errors and asks if it will "work" if they are fixed. Here is one error: `#define SOME_OPERATION(a,b) a+b` should be `#define SOME_OPERATION(a,b) ((a)+(b))`

Comment: "*When I write SomeType a, Does it mean that a new pointer to SomeType was allocated*". No it doesn't. That's a struct so it is a struct that is allocated. It's allocated on the stack which make `return &a` wrong as it is invalid to return a pointer to a local variable. Need to `malloc` the memory instead of allocating on the stack if it is to be returned.

Comment: Putting code it seems you would always want to run like `a.nameLen = strlen(name);` inside an assert that can be conditionally compiled out is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: `assert` is a macro that may or may not be a no-op. Meaning that the assignment `a.nameLen = strlen(name)` may or may not be ignored.

Comment: @kaylum. Rather than `malloc`-ing a new struct and returning a pointer, it is allso possible to return the struct itself

Comment: At line 20 you return NULL without freeing a.name

Comment: @HAL9000 Yeah sure can. Though in the context of the OP code the function is defined to return  a pointer and that's what I was referring to. If we change the return type to the struct type then yes we can/should return the struct itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should properly format the code in your question.

1. You return a reference to the automatic variable. This variable does not exist after the function return. It is undefined behaviour.

You need to dynamically allocate this object:

```
SomeType *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
```

and

```
return a;
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if this fixed code works for this specific issue:

```
if(!a.name)
{
  //or should be in addition free(a)
  return NULL;
}
```

`a` is not a pointer. a is an object of the structure type `SomeType`. So there is nothing to free.

> When I write SomeType a, Does it mean that a new pointer to SomeType
> was allocated?

Neither pointer is allocated. There is defined the object `a` of the type `SomeType` having automatic storage duration.

Returning a pointer to the object

```
return &a
```

makes the pointer invalid because the object `a` will not be alive after exiting the function. Dereferencing such a pointer in the caller of the function results in undefined behavior.

Instead of returning a pointer to an object of the type `SomeType` you could return an object of the type `SomeType` itself.

Answer (score -1):

> For example in line 14, there it doesn't check if malloc returns NULL. My question is, if this fixed code works for this specific issue:

No, your instinct is correct. Every `malloc` (or `realloc`ed area) needs a `free`.

> When I write SomeType a, Does it mean that a new pointer to SomeType was allocated?

No, that would require a *constructor* - something that is not available in the C language. You will have to create free *constructing* functions to manage the relationship similarly in C.